# Facebook Like Button Post to Facebook Box is Not Showing Properly?

Tags: css, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am Using the XFBML of Social Plugins I created the Popup For this and Place the XFBML Code For Testing. Like Button is Working Fine. After Like Post to Facebook Box is not Appearing Properly. I am Not Sure Why this Happening. I attached the Screenshot for this one
[image: Here is the Screenshot]

Any Suggestion Would Be Great. I am Using this code on Wordpress Site.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Typically that means that overflow is set to hidden on one of the like buttons' parents (causing the extra content to be cut off.) I would check your CSS for that first of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn off "sending" and "show faces" functions for it. XFBML code should thendisplay the button look something like this:

```
<fb:like href="yoursite.com" send="false" layout="box_count" width="150" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Other thing could be that the FB button is partially overlayed by another layer. Try to wrap the code above to `<div></div>`, create a class for this `div` like that `<div class="myclass"></div>` and then use a `z-index` css property like this:

```
.myclass {
   z-index: 1;
}
```